# How to implement an ODE solution with periodic boundary condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numerical-integration

The system I would like to study (in python 2.7) is formed by a few number of particles that interact with a "prime-neighbor" potential, the particles are shaped like a chain and the potential is armonic with a small anarmonic perturbation.

First I've written a simulation using fixed boundary condition (I put all the particles at 0. position and all the velocities on the first oscillation mode, then I kept fixed at 0. the positions of the first and last particle) but now, because I would like to show some mathematical results about kinetic energy I need to re-write my program with periodic boundary conditions.

Now I can't find any clear example of how could I do for my problem, it is an ODE.

I tried simply, like in the theory,  to put the first and the last particle of the system as equal in position and velocity, but in this way I see that the mass centre moves in a certain direction that depends from initial data.

So I tried to subtract, at every step of my integrator, the mass centre position from all the positions of the particles but, in this way, the energy of the system has a really large oscillation (I was using leapfrog 4th order integrator for my first program with fixed boundary conditions because I need a very good total energy conservation) , I would like to see an exemple of how to write down in python 2.7 periodic boundary condition for ODE resolution but in 1D, because my particles oscillate in a 1D domain.

I am really sorry for bad English.

Comment: you'd probably get better responses if you asked more *specific* questions. Asking people for examples of an "ODE" in python probably isn't going to get you much. But if you use google ("python ordinary differential equation example") you might some other people with ODE examples: http://sam-dolan.staff.shef.ac.uk/mas212/notebooks/ODE_Example.html

Comment: I asked for how to implement periodic boundary condition, not how to solve an ODE. Thanks for your help, but I already tried with Google.